# Одинаковые массивы при сравнении дают false

Tags: javascript

```js
console.log(( [] == [] )); // false
```

объясните почему так получилось ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/how-to-compare-arrays-in-javascript

Comment: Потому что разные объекты.

Comment: @Alexander Chernin там по английски

Comment: @Эникейщик почему ведь это объекты ?

Comment: Что "почему"???

Comment: @Эникейщик массив это ведь объект

Comment: А я что написал?

Comment: @Эникейщик  тут указаны 2 массива это объекты; значит true

Comment: Это **разные** объекты. По ссылке в первом комментарии всё написано.

Comment: @Эникейщик понял что ничего не понял; как они могут быть разными если если это объект и объект

Comment: Жигули и Тойота тоже машина и машина. Одинаковые?

Comment: @Эникейщик оба транспортные средства

Comment: Когда == начнёт сравнивать на "тоже ли транспортное средство", то будет true.  А пока что нет.